# How to build the Android M preview appcompat support library?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-appcompat

With the Android-M preview also a preview of the new support library has been released (See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170105#c12)

I found the source code (or at least I think I found it) of the support preview library here:

```
sdk/sources/android-MNC/android/support/v7
```

But there don't seem to be any resources provided with it, only java code. I tried to create a new module in Android Studio and added the resources from the current appcompat version (22.2) to it and it seems to work.

But the gradle build fails because it can't find certain R files, like:

```
android.support.v7.preference.R;
android.support.v7.mediarouter.R;
```

**How exactly should I build the preview version of the appcompat library, for use with Android Studio?**

Comment: AFAIK, you don't build it, at least before it ships (i.e., exits pre-release status) and can be obtained from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/.